# Basic question on function mapping and FOL

Tags: functions, first-order-logic

Let the sets $X=\{1,2\}$ and $Y=\{2,3\}$. Let $[1 \in X \rightarrow 2 \in Y] \land [2 \in X \rightarrow 3\in Y]$. Is it possible, in first-order logic, to substitute the statements $2\in Y$ and $3\in Y$ by $1+1\in Y$ and $2+1\in Y$ respectively, thus, concluding that the entire expression is equivalent to $[1 \in X \rightarrow 1+1 \in Y] \land [2 \in X \rightarrow 2+1\in Y]$ and to the mapping $\forall x \in X \hspace{0.5em} \exists y \in Y \hspace{0.5em} y = x+1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using the [substitution axiom for equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms):

> $x=y \to (\varphi \to \varphi')$, where $\varphi'$ is obtained from $\varphi$ replacing any number of free occurrences of $x$ with $y$.

Thus, provided that we have an axiom of theorem stating that $1+1=2$, we can use it with formula $\varphi := [1∈X → 2∈Y] ∧ [2∈X → 3∈Y]$ to get $[1∈X → 1+1∈Y]∧[1+1∈X → 3∈Y]$, and then replace $3$.

Comment: Thank you, Mr Allegranza. That means, in a more general level, that if we have the pairwise distinct sets $X=\{a,b\}$ and $Y=\{c,d\}$, the formula $[a \in X \rightarrow c \in Y] \land [b \in X \rightarrow d \in Y]$ is the mapping of some function from X to Y?

Comment: @TylerD007 - every formula $\varphi(x,y)$ for which we can prove that $\forall x \exists ! y \varphi(x,y)$ holds will be interpreted in a domain $D$ whatever as a (one argument place) function on $D$ (and the same for multiple arguments).